# Como obtener cantidad de registros diarios durente cierto periodo con laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel, querybuilder

estoy realizando una consulta con el query builder de laravel, mi objetivo es obtener es obtener cuantas ventas se realizaron cada dia durante cierto periodo (por ejemplo durante cierto mes, año o fecha), pero no he podido obtener las ventas por cada dia, solo puedo obtenerlo si el parametro es una fecha especifica, asi:

```
$sales = DB::table('productables')->select(DB::raw("count(*) as cantidad_ventas"))
        ->join('orders','orders.id','=','productable_id')
        ->whereDate('orders.created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->whereIn('productable_type', [Order::class])
        ->get();
```

Y las tablas son de la siguiente forma:

orders:

- id (PK)
- total (int)
- sale_date (date)
- created_at (timestamp)

productables:

- product_id (fk a product)
- quantity (int) (es la cantidad de cierto producto registrada en la orden)
- productable_type (es el modelo a cual corresponde ya que es una tabla polimorfica de laravel)
- productable_id (es la fk a la orden)

Como puedo decirle que me arroje cuantos registros hay en cada dia durante cierto periodo?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ gracias! me funciono, era justo lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude solucionar el problema, solo debia agrupar la consulta por la fecha:

```
$sales = DB::table('productables')->select(DB::raw("count(*) as cantidad_ventas"))
        ->join('orders','orders.id','=','productable_id')
        ->whereIn('productable_type', [Order::class])
        ->groupBy('orders.created_at');
        ->get();
```